# How to catch XML Dom with php regex

Tags: php, regex, xml, parsing, atom-feed

I got some XML Atom files on local.
On all of those files, there are some `<author>...</author>` balise that I want to catch in a PHP string variable.

So I did that :

```
function parseAtomByBalise($xml,$balise) {
    $arrayStr=array();
    preg_match('#<'.$balise.'>(.*)</'.$balise.'>#',$xml,$arrayStr);

    return $arrayStr;
}
 $fxml=fopen($xml,'r');
    $strXML=fgets($fxml);
    echo '<p>author: <textarea>';
    $authors=parseAtomByBalise($strXML,'author');
    foreach($authors as $author) {
        if($author!=$strXML)
            echo $author.'\n';
    }
    echo '</textarea></p>';
}
```

Files are opening, and strXML is the good string.
I got some stranges behaviours of preg_match, that makes me think that this is not the good function... I got more balises than only the balises insides `<author></author>`

How should I do ?

Comment: PHP has an [XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php). Use it.

Comment: Why don't you parse XML instead of using regex? I mean, bad things could happen... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/236345

Comment: Ok I didnt know that HTML is too much complicate to be parsed by regular expression. Thank you, I go use XML parser

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't try to reinvent the wheel.
2. `Regex` is not good for parsing XML(just an [example](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html), not the absolute proof, but...)
3. use the `PHP` built in tools like [simple XML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)